# Getting specific set of lines when pattern matches

Tags: bash, unix

Input

```
abc  
cde  
efg  
xyz  
abc  
jkl  
mno  
xyz
```

Now i want to get the lines between pattern abc and xyz but for the second match.

output

```
cde  
efg
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before post something.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/abc/{count++;next} count==2{flag=1}  /xyz/ && flag{print val;val=flag=""} flag{val=val?val ORS $0:$0}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

```
awk '
/abc/{                    ##Checking condition here if a line is having string abc in it then do following.
   count++;               ##Increment variable named count with 1 each time cursor comes here.
   next}                  ##Using next keyword which will skip all further statements written.
count==2{                 ##Checking condition here if a variable count value is 2 here then do following.
   flag=1}                ##Setting variable named flag value is set to 1 here.
/xyz/ && flag{            ##Checking conditions here is a line is having string xyz and variable named flag is SET here then do following.
   print val;             ##Printing variable named val here.
   val=flag=""}           ##Nullifying variable val and flag here.
flag{                     ##Checking condition here if variable flag value is NOT NULL then do following.
   val=val?val ORS $0:$0  ##Create variable named val and concatenate its value with its own value each time cursor comes here.
}' Input_file             ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 0):

**`Awk`** approach:

```
awk '/abc/ && ++c == 2{ f = 1; next }/xyz/{ f = 0 }f' file
```

The output:

```
jkl
mno
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `sed` you must do something for finding the second hit.
First select the lines that match. That way you are sure that the first line will be `abc` when there are matches (I do not write `^abc$`, perhaps a substring should match too).

```
sed -n '/abc/,/xyz/ p' inputfile
```

Now delete until the second `abc`. When your input only has one `abc` all lines are deleted.

```
sed '/abc/,/abc/d'
```

When you alse delete lines from `xyz` until EOF, this will be

```
sed -n '/abc/,/xyz/ p' inputfile | sed '/abc/,/abc/d; /xyz/,$ d'
```